# Counting number of occurrence in randomly generated numbers

Tags: java, random

I have a Java program that generates 100 random integers between 0 and 9 and I need to make it display the count for each number. the example of that is this:

```
*************************************************************************
Generating 100 random integers between 0 and 9
Number 1 = 3
Number 2 = 0
… (your program must display all generated numbers)
Number 100 = 8
*************************************************************************
0 occurs 1 time
1 occurs 9 times
2 occurs 18 times
3 occurs 20 times
4 occurs 5 times
5 occurs 20 times
6 occurs 1 time
7 occurs 1 time
8 occurs 25 times
9 occurs 0 time
*************************************************************************
```

So far I have this much:

```
 import java.util.Random;
    public class World {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        public void generateNumber(){
System.out.println("*************************************************************************");
           System.out.println("Generating 100 random integers between 0 and 9");

        Random aGenerator = new Random();

        int randomArray[]=new int[101];
        int countArray[]=new int[10];

        //generate the numbers and store into an array
        int j;
        for(int i=1; i<101; ++i) {
            j=i;
                randomArray[i]=aGenerator.nextInt(10);

                //displaying numbers
                  System.out.println("Number " + j + " = " + randomArray[i]);

            }



 System.out.println("*************************************************************************");

//counting the numbers
for(int i=1;i<100;i++){
    countArray[randomArray[i]-1] = countArray[randomArray[i]-1]+1;

//displaying the counts
    j=i;
    System.out.println(randomArray[i]+" occurs "+countArray[i]+ " times");

    }




           }
}
}
```

and the generating and displaying random numbers work fine, however, the counting part looks like this

```
*************************************************************************
5 occurs 0 times
7 occurs 0 times
7 occurs 0 times
9 occurs 1 times
2 occurs 0 times
2 occurs 2 times
1 occurs 0 times
4 occurs 1 times
    at Generator.generateNumber(2 appears 0 times
Generator.java:33)
    at World.main(World.java:17)
```

Please help me by telling which part I did wrong? Thank you so much for your time!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. When posting new questions, please be sure to tag the programming language you're using. It'll help people answer your question more quickly. Also, you don't need to post the IDE you're using in the question unless it has an effect on your code. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is more complicated than it need be. Just use:

```
//to store the counts
for (int r : randomArray)
    countArray[r]++;

//to access the counts
for (int x = 0; x < countArray.length; x++) {
    System.out.println("" + x + " occurs " + countArray[x] + " times");
}
```

Comment: I think `for (int r: randomArray) countArray[r]++;` would be less complicated ;)

Comment: As you wish. :) I agree, good call.